# Power Series - Reference Request (?)

Tags: analysis, reference-request, power-series

I'm not sure if I've tagged that correctly as a reference request or not, but I'm nearly done with Kenneth Ross's book Elementary Analysis, and one of the topic's that's caught my interest to learn more about was the treatment of series, and in particular, power series. I'm fond of differential equations as a subject, and I know that there is an important relationship to studying power series and understanding many types of differential equations. I'm also particularly interested in dynamics and chaos, and am curious to seek out any connections between the two subjects, as I know that dynamic systems that arise as solutions to non-linear differential equations are not uncommon.

Does anyone have any sources that would make sense for an undergraduate just finishing their first Analysis course in either of these contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this book

- [Theory and Application of Infinite Series](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Theory_and_Application_of_Infinite_Serie.html?id=qLPxxeBzp84C&redir_esc=y) by Konrad Knopp.

Comment: Admittedly, this response is from a very long time ago, but I just figured I'd let you know that I did pick up this text, and although the writing is a bit older, so a bit harder to read, after getting through about half of it, I am thoroughly pleased with it.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Principles of Mathematical Analysis by W.Rudin.
It would be the next step in Analysis and he deals with power series too.

After that you might find interesting reading something in Complex Analysis and Laurent series http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series. A textbook in this topic would be Complex Analysis by T.W.Gamelin.

Comment: I've actually got this text. A friend gave it to me at the start of the semester but it was way over my head at that time. I forgot completely. I should go revisit it!